# Add items to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this:

```
$errors = new array();
```

There are some PHP-variables which contain data:

```
$errorID = 0;
$errorTxt = 'Success! You have been registered!';
$errorID2 = 1;
$errorTxt2 = 'Failure! Something went wrong!!';
```

My question is:

Is it possible to add data to the array in this way:

```
$errors[$errorID] = $errorTxt;
$errors[$errorID2] = $errorTxt2;
```

Also I'd like to know how do you iterate the array so I can get the value of a certain key? Just wanted to mention that this is an associative array...

Comment: Yes it is possible.. Loop with foreach:

http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Why don't you just test if it's possible? You've allready written the code for the question. Run it and see what happens, it works. By the way: `$errors = array();` is enough, no need for the new. Also elments of associative arrays are still accessible trough their index, if you need an element by its position.

Comment: *"so I can get the value of a certain key"* You don't have to iterate over the array for that. You just access it: `$arr[$someKey]`. Learn the basics about arrays: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Barmar SO is definitely not "a school" it's "THE ultimate school" :) I can't really express how much I learned (and keep learning) from the community members here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you had to do is add

```
var_dump($errors);
```

and run the code - and you would see that it works fine.

You don't "parse" an array - you parse a string.

You can iterate an associative array using foreach loop:

```
foreach($errors as $k => $v)
    echo "$k $v"
```